# How to re-create CSS hover animation on an input using jQuery so it works in Edge

Tags: jquery, html, css, microsoft-edge, jquery-hover

I have anywhere from six to nine switches that are `<input type="checkbox">` lined up in a row. Each switch animates on hover: the knob slides down and both the knob and the track fill with either a solid color or a gradient. In Edge, the hover animation doesn't fire.

I don't understand jQuery enough to know where to begin in re-creating this animation using jQuery instead of CSS so that it works in Edge.

I don't know what I need to leave in the CSS code or what I should move to jQuery.

I understand that the issue is that Edge doesn't like `hover` on anything but links (at least that's what I've been told).

How do I get this working using jQuery instead of CSS?

I've looked at other people questions and the answers they've received but they all deal with images or links or something simple, not inputs. I've put together a codepen with some comments: https://codepen.io/akajezebel/pen/PrQoJe

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="switch-row">
       <label class="switch">
         <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
           <input class="knob" type="checkbox">
           <span class="slider round"></span>
         </a>
         </label>
      </div>
      <div class="switch-row">
       <label class="switch">
          <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <input class="knob" type="checkbox">
           <span class="slider round"></span>
         </a>
       </label>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The CSS:

```
.switch {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 113px;
      margin: 10px 23px;
      position: relative;
      width: 55px;
    }

    .switch input {
      height: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      width: 0;
    }

    .slider {
      border: 1px solid #cc80ff;
      bottom: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      -moz-transition: 0.4s;
      -o-transition: 0.4s;
      -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .slider::before {
      border: 1px solid #cc80ff;
      bottom: 60px;
      content: "";
      height: 43px;
      left: 5px;
      position: absolute;
      -moz-transition: 0.4s;
      -o-transition: 0.4s;
      -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
      transition: 0.4s;
      width: 43px;
    }

    input:hover + .slider {
      background-color: #cc80ff;
      background-color: rgba(204, 128, 255, 0.8);
    }

    input:focus + .slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #cc80ff;
    }

    input:hover + .slider::before {
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #cc80ff, #e4d8cb, #cc80ff);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom right, #cc80ff, #e4d8cb, #cc80ff);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #cc80ff, #e4d8cb, #cc80ff);
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #cc80ff, #e4d8cb, #cc80ff);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #cc80ff, #e4d8cb, #cc80ff);
      -moz-transform: translateY(54px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(54px);
      -o-transform: translateY(54px);
      -webkit-transform: translateY(54px);
      transform: translateY(54px);
    }

    /* ----- Rounded sliders ----- */
    .slider.round {
      border-radius: 34px;
    }

    .slider.round::before {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

The jQuery that I'm using as a guide to see if I can figure this out, but that I don't understand. I borrowed this from http://jsfiddle.net/q61n8gxv/2/ :

```
jQuery.easing['jswing'] = jQuery.easing['swing'];
jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
  easeOutBounce: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t /= d) < (1 / 2.75)) {
      return c * (7.5625 * t * t) + b
   } else if (t < (2 / 2.75)) {
      return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (1.5 / 2.75)) * t + .75) + b
    } else if (t < (2.5 / 2.75)) {
      return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (2.25 / 2.75)) * t + .9375) + b
    } else {
      return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (2.625 / 2.75)) * t + .984375) + b
    }
  }
});

//This bit I understand, but I don't know how this works with CSS or the above. 
$('.slider').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        top: -50
    },900, "easeOut");
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        top: 0
    }, 900, "easeOut");
});
```

I expect the switches to work like they do in CSS but using jQuery instead. I want the knob to slide down and fill with a gradient and the track to fill with a solid color on `hover`/`mouseenter` and to revert on `mouseout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE probably doesn't see your input being size down to 0.
try this approach

```css
.switch {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 113px;
  margin: 10px 23px;
  position: relative;
  width: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.001;
  z-index: 1
}

.slider {
  border: 1px solid #cc80ff;
  bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.slider::before {
  border: 1px solid #cc80ff;
  bottom: 60px;
  content: "";
  height: 43px;
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  -moz-transition: 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  width: 43px;
}

input:hover+.slider {
  background-color: #cc80ff;
  background-color: rgba(204, 128, 255, 0.8);
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #cc80ff;
}

input:hover+.slider::before {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, #cc80ff, #e4d8cb, #cc80ff);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom right, #cc80ff, #e4d8cb, #cc80ff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, #cc80ff, #e4d8cb, #cc80ff);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, #cc80ff, #e4d8cb, #cc80ff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #cc80ff, #e4d8cb, #cc80ff);
  -moz-transform: translateY(54px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(54px);
  -o-transform: translateY(54px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(54px);
  transform: translateY(54px);
}


/* ----- Rounded sliders ----- */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

​
```

```html
<div class="switch-row">
  <label class="switch">
         <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
           <input class="knob" type="checkbox">
           <span class="slider round"></span>
         </a>
         </label>
</div>
<div class="switch-row">
  <label class="switch">
          <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <input class="knob" type="checkbox">
           <span class="slider round"></span>
         </a>
       </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @G-cyr. This approach gets the animation firing in Edge, however, the effect is hit and miss. I can hover outside the input and it fires (unexpected). I can hover over the input and it may or may not fire. And if I hover directly over the knob part (the circle), it fires but stops quickly. There is a spot in the middle of the track where it flickers on hover. Sometimes when I hover over the circle, nothing at all happens until I move my mouse to a certain point. I need it to be smooth and predictable like it is in the other browsers. I'm using Browserstack to test it on Edge.

Comment: @BabyThunderball i only run ie11 at the moment , maybe set hover on the label (:focus  will be on the input anyway)instead, else, to debug, remove opacity from the input to see better where it stands to adjust size and position.

Comment: @BabyThunderball i updated the snippet to make the input the full width and height of the label . tell me if that works better. The thing is that to trigger :hover , element needs a size and not opacity equal to 0/none. this is the point you have to mind about ;)

Comment: Thanks, @G-cyr running IE11! That works perfectly! I didn't think I could do it without jQuery! You've saved me a lot of hassle! :)

Comment: @G-cyrrunningIE11 Any reason you have a second account just for IE11 answers and don't just answer with your normal account?

Comment: @TylerH about IE11, soon out of date if not yet, you better run a genuine one and check it twice if you want to help efficiently (sometimes i get mixed up with IE8 behavior) .beside  I do not mind about reputation score. This account will be soon useless